# Is the sequence of $\mathbb Z$-modules below exact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I came across the following example in my algebra textbook:

Considere the sequence of $\mathbb Z$-modules: $$0\longrightarrow \mathbb Z_2\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb Z_4\stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb Z_2\longrightarrow 0,$$

where $f$ is the isomorphism of $\mathbb Z_2$ and the unique proper subgroup $2\mathbb Z_4$ of $\mathbb Z_4$ and $g$ is the multiplication by $2$. This is an exact short sequence.

I guess there is something strange here for if the sequence were exact $\textrm{im}(g)=\mathbb Z_2=\{\overline{0}, \overline{1}\}$ but if there were $\overline{a}\in \mathbb Z_4$ such that $2\overline{a}=\overline{1}$ in $\mathbb Z_2$ then $2|2a-1$ what certainly can't happen.

Am I missing something?

**Reference:** Algèbre et Modules (I. Assem, pg. 31).

Comment: No, $g$ would not be surjective.  Are you sure you have the definition of $g$ correct?

Comment: Pretty sure, I just copied it from the book..

Comment: Then it must be a typo or some other mistake the author has made.

Comment: Yeah, it must be.. Indeed, $g$ would be the trivial map, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yep.  Trivial map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get an exact sequence there is to have $g$ = reduction mod $2$.

"Multiplication by 2" is the description of $f$, not $g$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the second $\Bbb Z_2$ is actually $2\Bbb Z_4$, that is, it is:

$\{[0]_4,[2]_4\}$ (this is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$).

It should be clear then,  that $gf = 0$, as one would expect in an exact sequence.